# Can I run a RAP-Application on Glassfish?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, glassfish, eclipse-rap

I should implement a part of a Client-Application as a Web-Application for Glassfish 4.0. Now I saw that there is RAP in Eclipse and it looks perfect for my case.

I already created a RAP Demo Project and in Eclipse it works perfect. But if I convert the project in a Maven Project and deploy the ".war" file on Glassfish it returns an error message.

So my question is if it's possible to run a RAP-Application on Glassfish and if yes, how can i do it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does it work with the [Eclipse WAR Product export wizard](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-03/topic/org.eclipse.rap.doc/guide/articles/deployment.html)? At least Glassfish 3 is supported since RAP 1.4: [_" Deploying RAP on application servers like Tomcat 7 or Glassfish 3. is now possible."_](https://www.eclipse.org/rap/noteworthy/1.4/)

Comment: Then I get this error on the Glassfish when I launch the application:

HTTP Status 404 - BridgeServlet: /rapdemo/workbench/
type Status report

messageBridgeServlet: /rapdemo/workbench/

descriptionThe requested resource is not available.

GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0

Comment: And in the log-file of the glassfish domain I get a lot of "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException"-exceptions

Answer (score 0):

I did it already with glassfish so yes, this works - without any extra hassle.

https://help.eclipse.org/2019-03/topic/org.eclipse.rap.doc/guide/articles/deployment.html has some hints, but if you give me your war file I can have a look at it as well.

P.S. [how to develop, build and deploy multiple OSGi based web applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55122898/how-to-develop-build-and-deploy-multiple-osgi-based-web-applications) gives you a hint you to get working war files as well.